# How to fix javascript from entering a breakline when translating PHP to JS?

Tags: javascript, php, file

I'm currently trying to read lines in php, (it has to be php), and logging them.
This works, as i'm getting

> $item1_name = $lines[1]; ----> 'MY ITEM NAME'

However, later on i have to use that $item1_name as a javascript variable:

> var item1 = ' < ? php echo $item1_name ? > ';

The problem is, as i am declaring my variable, the console will output a breakline, because in my txt file, i entered a new line to declare the $item1_size.

Hence, my code will not work as javascript is experiencing an unexpected line break.

I kinda have no idea how to disable javascript from executing a breakline, as my txt file has to have multiple lines.

Help would be appreciated!

Thank you

---

**SOLVED**
Trimming it directly in the variable has fixed it.

Comment: use addslashes function

Comment: Show the PHP you use to get the lines and whatever `$item1_size` has to do with it.

Comment: did you try `trim`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are splitting the text file with `\n` where the text file uses `\r\n` as the line breaks. Try using:

```
$item1_name = trim($lines[1]);
```

or

```
var item1 = '<?php echo trim($item1_name);?>';
```

to eliminate the whitespace around your string.

PHP's `trim` function is structured like this:

> trim ( string $str [, string $character_mask = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] ) : string

which means the second optional parameter containing the characters `[space]\t\n\r\0\x0B` defines which characters to remove from the begining and the end. You can extend them to whatever you like.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Ohh trimming it directly in the var has fixed my problem!

Comment: Apologies. Thanks again.